# php file does not accept css

Tags: php, html, css

I have written a contact form about php. I would like the input fields and the text output to be centered. Since I created the input fields with the form tag, I thought it would be sufficient if I insert the centering in the CSS file with the form tag. However, the place ignores the CSS file (all other settings on the page work above the CSS file). What could be the reason?

I've already tried .form, #form and only form, but has no effect

**CSS:**

```
form { 
    width:300px;
    height:160px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-80px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff?"><br>
      <textarea name="nachricht" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht!"> 
      </textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Absenden!"><br>
 </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $betreff = $_POST['betreff'];
    $nachricht = $_POST['nachricht'];
    $absenden = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO kontakt(betreff,nachricht,datum) VALUES (?,?,NOW())");
    $absenden->bind_param('ss',$betreff,$nachricht);
    $absenden->execute();
endif;

$abfrage = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kontakt ORDER BY datum DESC");

echo 'Es wurden '.$abfrage->num_rows.' Nachrichten gefunden!<br>';

while($ausgabe = $abfrage->fetch_object()){
    echo '<b>Betreff:</b> '.$ausgabe->betreff.' <br>
          <b>Nachricht:</b><br> '.$ausgabe->nachricht.' <br>
          <hr>';
}
```

Actually I would like to have the contact form in the middle, but I would be glad if he would react to the CSS statement at all.
As already said, only the contact form is left out. The rest works.

Comment: Form submission creates an entirely distinct HTML page to be sent to the browser. And a CSS rule for `form` will not cover unrelated flowtext. Use view-source to see what you got.

Comment: @mario what do you mean: `Use view-source to see what you got.`?

Comment: apply semantically correct html page structure

Comment: @sharete are you sure `"css/style.css"` loads? Press `Ctrl + Shift + I` to see any 404 errors in the console.

Comment: @Raphael can you be a little more specific, please?

Comment: @sharete Also I see no `body` tag?

Comment: @vivek_23 okay, it's something else. strangely enough, he doesn't show it on my laptop, but he does on my desktop pc.
i tried several browsers on my laptop now, but it shows me everything as if it were ignoring the css file. as soon as i open the website on my desktop pc, everything is as i want it to be.

Comment: @sharete Ok, I would need more context to debug. Also, what do you mean by `he doesn't show it on my laptop, but he does on my desktop pc`? I noticed that you also missed `type='text/css'` on your `link` tag.

Comment: use structure as as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure

Comment: @vivek_23 i mean that on notebook the contact form is still on the left, although it is defined differently in css.
as soon as i call up the page on the desktop pc, the contact form is in the middle as defined in the css. where to add `type='text/ss'`?

Comment: So, a question about browser caching then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form is `inline` by default, so all the `margin`, `width` and `height` css won't affect it the way you want. You need to add:

`display:block;`

to your css.

The other thing is that `left:50%` won't center it properly (I guess that is why You have used the `margin` correction), would suggest to use `margin: auto`, or `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto`. That way you won't need to correct it manually (note: that won't affect the vertical align). It is possible that it won't work without setting the proper `absolute` / `relative` positioning correlation.

Totally different way of centering things is to put them into the table with one cell with vertical and horizontal align set to `center` / `middle`. You need to set your `html,body` elements `width` and `height` to `100%` as well as table dimensions. The way is a bit of workaround, but it works perfectly even on older browsers. Please note that in that case the `form` has to stay `inline`, so don't add `display:block` if you gonna use that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only positioning information you have is to position the form on the page. There is no alignment information that the inputs would properly inherit.  I would recommend styling INPUT in your CSS file, and not relying on the FORM style to get you what you want.  Styling INPUT separately from the FORM will also give you much more control later on.